# $a + b + c$ divides $a^n + b^n + c^n$?(Canadian math Olympiad 2005)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

$(a,b,c)$ is $n$-*powerful* if

1.) $a ≤ b ≤ c$

2.) $(a,b,c)$ $= 1$

3.) $a + b + c$ $|$ $a^n + b^n + c^n$

Find all $n$-powerful triples.

First off, I'm guessing when it says 'find all n-powerful triples, it means find $a,b,c$ in terms of $n$

I let $a,b,c$ be roots of a monic cubic polynomial where the coefficients are integers, or, $x^3 + px^2 + qx + r$ $= 0$. $a^k + b^k + c^k = S_k$ then we have:

$S_1 = -p$

$S_2 = p^2 - 2q$

$S_3 = (-p)(p^2 - 3q) + 3r$

And in general,with a little playing around with vieta's coefficient relations and some algebraic identities, we can get:

$6S_k - 6(S_1)S_{k-1} + 3(S_1^2 - S_2)S_{k-2} + (3S_1S_2 - S_1^3 - 2S_3)(S_{k-3})$ $= 0$

Modulo $S_1$ this is:

$6S_k - 3(S_2)S_{k-2} - (2S_3)(S_{k-3})$ $= 0$

So, if $S_1$ divides $S_k$, as is given, then $S_1$ divides

$3S_2S_{k-2} + 2S_3S_{k-3}$.

What do I do from here

Comment: $a,b,c\in\Bbb Z$? Or $\in\Bbb N$? Or $\in \Bbb N_0$?

Comment: Famously$$a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca) +3abc.$$

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$...

Comment: @Hagen von Elitzen. Sorry that's a mistake. $p$ does not divide $S_3$

Comment: Page 12 of this report gives two solutions.  Note that the original problem says, $n$-powerful _for all $n$._  https://www2.cms.math.ca/Reports/cmo/2005-cmo-report-en.pdf